# Cordova android app shifts partially offscreen when virtual keyboard disappears

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

When the keyboard appears, our app will shift up as expected. However, when the keyboard then goes away, the graphical part of the app will shift down too much. What is weird, though, is that the actual interface of the app is unaffected: buttons can only be interacted with at their original position. We are using Cordova 3.5.0.

Some of my screenshots of the bug and it's effects:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/62vx36a4c3k49lm/AADpPZ6tCgj_qaDJBEFaea3pa.

The bug will not occur with the following code, unless `overflow: hidden` is added to `body/html or if`position: fixed` is added to the canvas. Without adding one of those parameters, however, the app will be too tall and the user will be able to scroll up and down.

CSS code:

```
body,html
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}

/* Size will be changed */
canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

The complete code for a minimal example of this bug is available on github at https://github.com/Diusrex/Cordova-ShiftScreen-Problem.

Comment: Same thing happening to me did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Dima No. I think it was a bug in Cordova, but I stopped working on that project pretty soon after I found the problem so I do not know for sure.